# Error: Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I've just installed Yeoman and created my first project. I'm trying to get my head around unit testing the default angular project that is created by Yo. The project runs fine when I invoke "grunt server", but when I run the unit test "grunt test:unit" I get the error "Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined".

What am i missing to get this test running properly?

Thanks again

-- controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.awesomeThings = [
'HTML5 Boilerplate',
'AngularJS',
'Karma',
'mytest'
  ];
});
```

-- unti test

```
 'use strict';

 describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

 // load the controller's module
 beforeEach(module('myApp'));

var MainCtrl,
 scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
 beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
 MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
 $scope: scope
});
}));

it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(4);
});
});
```

Comment: Did you define the module myApp using: angular.module('myApp', [])

Comment: I defined it in the unit test. Do I need to define it somewhere else as well?

Comment: it fails on this line: MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: scope }); in the unit test. the files are included in the conf file. not sure what else to check.

Comment: you postet your controller file. replace angular.module('myApp') with angular.module('myApp', []). Do you still get an error?

Comment: aha! that was it! I was referencing the module. As soon as I changed the code to angular.module('myApp',[]) the test is running now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If I copy and paste this code it is executed without problems. The error message you're getting indicates that the controller (name) isn't known to the injector. Did you forget to include the controller javascript file in the *karma.conf.js*?

Comment: hi there, in my karma.conf I've got wilcards for the folders that contain my controller and my tests. Am I missing a dependency or something?   files: [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/scripts/*.js',
            JASMINE,
            JASMINE_ADAPTER,
            'test/spec/controllers/*.js'
        ],

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a copy of "app.js" which was causing this same error. While it wasn't used in html page anywhere, as grunt test was including /**/* pattern, it was included and thus duplicating definition of module, probably resetting the controllers loaded from `app.js`. So I was getting errors like:

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areqp0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Once I removed this file, everything was working fine. It took me long time to figure what went wrong, but finally found the cause.